Geonames.com - "expected" subdivisions
I'm updating long-outdated lists of countries and states/provinces in my company's software. I want to use Geonames.com for various reasons.
I can easily pull a list of ADM2 names and their countries, which gives me the second item in a country's hierarchy. Sometimes this gives what I think a user would expect in a state/province dropdown (e.g. United States -> list of 50 states) but sometimes the first division isn't what most people would expect. For example, the ADM2 level for Ireland returns 4 provinces (which don't even have formal administrative usage) when most users would expect the list to show Ireland's various counties.
The problem is that the expected list is ADM3 for Ireland but ADM2 for the US. I can say which should be used for some countries but not for others (I have no idea which level of granularity is appropriate for, say, Bangladesh).
ISO's subdivision list shows what I'd expect, and CLDR has two levels of subdivision, with the second left blank if it's irrelevant (e.g. for the US), but I'm really hoping to use Geonames.
Is there some way to get this data in Geonames without having to individually determine whether ADM2 or ADM3 is more appropriate?
I've tried the various hierarchy options (geographical, tourism, dependencies) and all return counties for Ireland (or comparable for other countries).
Expected: a list of "commonly-understood" subdivisions of countries
Actual: the highest level subdivision, regardless of whether it's the "commonly-understood" subdivision
